# Pass multiple variables via Ajax url

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I try to sent `2` values from my view to controller by Ajax and get back their results in laravel,

here is my `script`:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('change', '#statehidden', function(e){
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
      });

       var cityname = $("#cityename").val();
       var statename = $("#statename").val();

      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('getcityandstate') }}/'+encodeURI(statename)'/'+encodeURI(cityname),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
          // $('#statehidden').empty();
          // $('#statehidden').append(data);
          alert('worked');
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

my `route`:

```
Route::get('/getcityandstate/{statename}/{cityname}','CartController@flatshippingcostincart');
```

my `controller`:

```
public function flatshippingcostincart(Request $request, $statename,$cityname) {
      $state = $request->statename;
      $city = $request->cityname;
      $shipping = Shipping::where('state', '=', $state)->where('city', '=', $city)->first();
      return response()->json($shipping);
}
```

## Errors

`in console`

```
SyntaxError: missing } after property list[Learn More] //in line 1200
note: { opened at line 1199, column 15 //in line 1199
```

`debugger`

```
line 1199 = $.ajax({
line 1200 = url: 'http://domain.../getcityandstate/'+encodeURI(statename)'/'+encodeURI(cityname),
```

## Questions

1. How can i attach my `var statename` and `var cityname` to my url?
2. My `$.ajax({` seems to be closed, why i get `SyntaxError: missing }
   after property list` error?

Comment: Escape the quotes `'{{ url(\'getcityandstate\') }}/'`

Comment: @RahilWazir that's not it, i get this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''getcityandstate\')); ?>/'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING)`

Comment: I assume function `url()` is executed by PHP, how would it interpret without PHP tags?

Comment: @RahilWazir that's the way laravel blade works. you don't have to use `<?php ... ?>` just simply use `{{ .... }}`

Comment: Yeah right. Try following `url: "{{ url('getcityandstate') }}/"+encodeURI(statename)+'/'+encodeURI(cityname),`. You were also missing JS concatenation `+` after `encodeURI(statename)`

Comment: @RahilWazir ok, i don't have error in my console but also i don't get my `alert('worked');`

Comment: Check your browsers network tab and whats the URL the request resolved to. Did you get any other status code than 200?

Comment: @RahilWazir nothing passes in network, just the 2 options i choose before print my state and city name, but for this function nothing

Comment: Are you triggering the change state? Once you do that, you may see request in Networks tab. Whats the URL output; the qualified URL? Does it resolves to the following example `http://example.com/getcityandstate/state/city` without any `{}` in the URL and whats the response from the server?

Comment: wait i test....

Comment: @RahilWazir ok, i couldn't get it to work when I changed my url to static values, but when i visit by url like: `http://domain/getcityandstate/Banten/Pandeglang` it does work, so i think issue is not from my route or controller but whatever it is is coming from this script itself.

Comment: @RahilWazir is there anyway i can `dumpdata` `var cityname` & `var statename` ? maybe they don't get values?

Comment: Put the url value to a variable `var _url = ...` and assign it to the ajax property `url: _url` and `console.log(_url)` to dump in console.

Comment: @ab_in already, base on rahilwazir comments i did that.

Comment: @RahilWazir nothing prints in console

Comment: @mafortis I got no error with your code.only change is add that `+`

Comment: @ab_in `var _url = "{{ url('"getcityandstate"') }}/"+encodeURI(statename)+'/'+encodeURI(cityname);` is that what you mean?

Comment: yup.. i was using static values as parameters.

Comment: @ab_in as you see this is like that but still i'm facing issues here.

Comment: you sure there is value in `cityname` and `statename`??? add a non empty check before the ajax call

Comment: @ab_in that's what i asked rahilwazir , she didn't answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473592/pass-multiple-variables-via-ajax-url#comment85950035_49473592 how can i check values of them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167500/discussion-between-ab-in-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 1):

Add a data item to to ajax object your sending.
**Data:{"key:"value","key":"value"}**
Make sure your sending a post request to your server..

if you insist on using get to send data to the server you have to rewrite the url, like

```
var item="mini",qty=2
then url:'www.yoursite.com?item="+item+"&quantity="+qty+"
```

Comment: post? i try to get data base on my info not to send them for store in database. are you sure?

Comment: then should i change my route as well?

Comment: If your to use post Yes just dont rewrite the url and use type post,